# base64 decode - как расшифровать эту строку

Tags: javascript, python, base64

Нашел на одном сайте меняется строка. В принципе этого мне достаточно, чтобы понять, что информация обновилась. но хотелось бы понимать содержимое. так как реч там о моделях машин.

сам сайт работает на js spa, я мониторю определенный урл там
мониторю я все это скриптом на python, requests

строка
"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"

пробовал через base64 decode но получается каша какая то.

у сайта рядом загружается файл wasm возможно эта каша для него предназначена. wasm я расшифровал

Comment: пунктуация, видимо, тоже для файла wasm предназначена и в этом вопросе отсутствует...

Comment: Ну да, какие-то бинарные данные, возможно пожатые или зашифрованные…